# Dynamically write table to file and allow download via link

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have some information I am pulling from my db into a table. Can anyone direct me to a tutorial that shows how to dynamically create a file and allow a user to download that file with the table contents. All this must be dynamic. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What database? and how do you want the file written? CSV? Excel? SQL dump? Just saying "a file" is useless. A file can be created with "echo > file.txt" at the command prompt, but would be useless for your user.

Comment: Did you check [DataTable.WriteXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hyx9hb4.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generate a dbml file using your database. See this article - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx

create a generic handler. do this inside of the handler ProcessRequest event:

```
public class MyData : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {   

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=\"myData.txt\"");   

        using(var db = new DbDataContext) {

            var data = db.Table.ToList(); //add Where(), OrderBy(), etc to filter and sort your data

            string fieldDelimeter = "\t";
            foreach(var item in data) {

                context.Response.Write(item.Field1 + fieldDelimeter);
                context.Response.Write(item.Field2 + fieldDelimeter);
                context.Response.Write(item.Field3 + fieldDelimeter);
                context.Response.Write(item.Field3 + fieldDelimeter);
                context.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an [ASHX handler](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx). In the handler, simply read the data from your database, and output it directly as text.

eg taken from the [link](http://www.aspcode.net/Creating-an-ASHX-handler-in-ASPNET.aspx):

```
public class RSSHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {   
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
        context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        string sXml = BuildXMLString(); 

        context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(600));
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
        context.Response.Write( sXml );
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```